# OData & Concurrency Token

Tags: c#-4.0, odata

I'm building an application that needs to be able to store data offline and sync it to an OData server. While reviewing the videos, one of the presenters mentioned a `Concurrency Token` - can this token be used to help in the sync process? If so, how do I use it and what do I need to watch out for?

For further info, my target platform is Android, so I'm unable to use the Microsoft Sync Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concurrency token, also called the ETag (as per the HTTP RFC) can be imagined as a version number of the entity instance. The server raises that every time the entity changes. The server sends this along with the entity to the client and the client can send it back to the server (in the If-Match header) when applying changes. The server will then check that the client has the latest version and if so applies the change. Otherwise it fails the update request.
It can help you with the sync process in two ways:
If you get an entity from the server and it has a differente ETag from what your client remembers, the server instance chas changed, so you may either update the client instance or perform some conflict resolution if the client made changes.
The other way would be to send all the changes from the client to the server (With the right ETags) and the server will fail all of those which already changed on the server. The client can then get the new versions from the server, resolve conflicts and try again.
Note though, that unless your ETag is one of the publicly accesible properties on the entity, there is no built-in way to filter on the ETag, so currently you can't ask the server to get you all entities changed since a given version. Although if you do control the service, you might be able to do this (have a global version number and each change raises that and each entity carries the version number of the last change made to it, then you can filter on that version property).